# Django urls points wrong path

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a production machines management application and I've encountered a strange problem that I can't solve.

Previously, I had a "Transactions" subpage with paths under the description with the same name. Everything was working very well.

Today I tried to add another sub-page, "Transactions per person" and the problem starts.

```
# Transaction
    path('transaction/machines', views.transaction_machines_list_view, name="transaction_machines_list"),
    path('transaction/machine/<int:id>', views.transaction_list_view, name="transaction_list"),
# Transaction per-Capita
    path('per_capita/employees', views.transaction_per_capita_employees_list_view, name="transaction_per_capita_employees_list"),
    path('per_capita/employee/<int:id>', views.transaction_per_capita_list_view, name="transaction_per_capita_list"),
```

All "transaction" paths works well, **per_capita/employees** works well too but when I try to reach the last one, for example

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/per_capita/employee/2
```

I encounter the following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /per_capita/employee/2
Reverse for 'transaction_list' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['transaction/machine/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
```

Why is my path named **transaction_per_capita_list** received as **transaction_list** by Django?
The redirect itself is a row in the table and looks like this:

```
<tr class="pointer" onclick="location.href='{% url 'transaction_per_capita_list' id=employee.id %}';">
   <td class="cell">{{ employee.username }}</td>
   <td class="cell">{{ employee.first_name }}</td>
   <td class="cell">{{ employee.last_name }}</td>
</tr>
```

This 2 views (feom views.py) looks like that:

```
# /per_capita/employees
@login_required
@permission_required('mes.view_transactionpercapita', raise_exception=True)
def transaction_per_capita_employees_list_view(request):
    data = {
        'employees': Employee.get_all()
    }
    return render(request, 'transaction_percap/employee_list.html', { 'data': data })


# /per_capita/employee/id
@login_required
@permission_required('mes.view_transactionpercapita', raise_exception=True)
def transaction_per_capita_list_view(request, id):
    employee = Employee.get_by_id(id)

    if request.GET.get('search'):
        transactions = TransactionPerCapita.find(employee, request.GET.get('search'))
    else:
        transactions = TransactionPerCapita.get_all(employee)

    paginator = Paginator(transactions, 15)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page') if request.GET.get('page') else 1
    transactions_page = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    paginator = {
        'actual_page': page_number,
        'has_next': transactions_page.has_next(),
        'has_prev': transactions_page.has_previous(),
        'last_page': paginator.num_pages
    }
    if paginator['has_next']: 
        paginator['next_page'] = transactions_page.next_page_number()
    if paginator['has_prev']: 
        paginator['prev_page'] = transactions_page.previous_page_number()

    data = {
        'employee': employee,
        'transactions': transactions_page,
        'paginator': paginator,
        'search': request.GET.get('search')
    }
    return render(request, 'transaction_percap/list.html', { 'data': data })
```

I've tried changing the path, I've tried renaming it and it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you import urls in project main urls file?

Comment: Yes, of course. These 4 paths I showed here are just a few from about 30 other url paths and everything works fine. Except this one :) I imported this urls in main urls file.

Comment: Could you share the view file?

Comment: It is not pointing to the wrong url the error says that while serving the request for `/per_capita/employee/2` there was an attempt to resolve / reverse for a url named `transaction_list` which failed. Likely this is a problem (typo?) in your view / template.

Comment: I've added these 2 views above (in edit). Path named **transaction_per_capita_list** should point **views.transaction_per_capita_list_view**, which returns **transaction_percap/list.html**.

Comment: Nevermind guys, I am so sorry for wasting your time. I've posted an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've just realised what I did.

It was not a problem with my urls or something, and this error was 100% correct.
In the template i was trying to render I had a few links used by paginator, like this:

```
<li class="page-item">
   <a class="page-link" href="{% url 'transaction_list' id=data.machine.id %}?page={{ data.paginator.prev_page }}&search={{ data.search | default_if_none:'' }}">
      Previous page
   </a>
</li>
```

As you can see, it points **transaction_list** but I have no *data.machine* in this view, so it throws an error. I am so sorry for this, I didn't know that it was that stupid :D